# Kafka appender added in log4j2.xml for a Mule ESB appllication

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, mule-esb

"I added kafka appender in log4j2.xml in Mule ESB appllication, I am getting the below error message in the log, Any one suggest how can i proceed ? "

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Callback
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.mom.kafka.KafkaAppender$Builder.build(KafkaAppender.java:68) ~[log4j-core-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.mom.kafka.KafkaAppender$Builder.build(KafkaAppender.java:53) ~[log4j-core-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:122) ~[log4j-core-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:952) ~[log4j-core-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:892) ~[log4j-core-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:884) ~[log4j-core-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:508) ~[log4j-core-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:232) ~[log4j-core-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:244) ~[log4j-core-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:545) ~[log4j-core-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:617) ~[log4j-core-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:634) ~[log4j-core-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.log4j2.MuleLoggerContext.reconfigure(MuleLoggerContext.java:86) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:229) ~[log4j-core-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.log4j2.LoggerContextCache.getLoggerContext(LoggerContextCache.java:162) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.log4j2.ArtifactAwareContextSelector.getContext(ArtifactAwareContextSelector.java:72) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.log4j2.ArtifactAwareContextSelector.getContext(ArtifactAwareContextSelector.java:66) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:147) ~[log4j-core-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45) ~[log4j-core-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194) ~[log4j-api-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:122) ~[log4j-api-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43) ~[log4j-slf4j-impl-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:46) ~[log4j-api-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]     at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29) ~[log4j-slf4j-impl-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358) ~[slf4j-api-1.7.24.jar:1.7.24]
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383) ~[slf4j-api-1.7.24.jar:1.7.24]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.DefaultResourceReleaser.<init>(DefaultResourceReleaser.java:33) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.AbstractArtifactClassLoader.createResourceReleaserInstance(AbstractArtifactClassLoader.java:110) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.AbstractArtifactClassLoader.dispose(AbstractArtifactClassLoader.java:67) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.CompositeApplicationClassLoader.dispose(CompositeApplicationClassLoader.java:285) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.dispose(DefaultMuleApplication.java:331) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$1.execute(ArtifactWrapper.javaorg.mule.module.launcher.StartupSummaryDeploymentListener:
```

Comment: You need to show us some code.

Comment: What jars are you bundling and deploying with your application?